# How to display data getting from Users Defaults array of dictionary to TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nsuserdefaults

1. [This image shows the functions i made to store and retrieve data from user defaults against a key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG8jy.png)
2. [This is my model class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB0Su.png)
3. [And this is where i retrieve data from userDefaults using function made in AppUtility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXVto.png)

I have stored my model in UserDefaults as an array of dictionaries, and i'm retrieving data from UserDefaults.
After retrieving data i'm storing it in an array initialized as:

var favouriteArray : [Any?] : []

```
favouritesArray = AppUtility.getCustomObjectOfKey(key: "wishlist") as! [Any?]

let cell:WishlistTableViewCell = (self.wishlistTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "wishlistCell") as! WishlistTableViewCell?)!
       
   let data = self.favouritesArray[indexPath.row]  as? [String:String]
   let data2 =  data["Product"]
```

When i try to get indexPath.row value from array it gives me nil in data.
anybody who can help Please!

favouriteArray:

[Optional(Product = {
"id" : "7435299225813",
"published_at" : null,
"options" : [
{
"product_id" : "7435299225813",
"id" : "9458706022613",
"name" : "Title",
"position" : "1",
"values" : [
"Default Title"
]
}
],
"admin_graphql_api_id" : "gid://shopify/Product/7435299225813",
"created_at" : "1970-01-01 00:00:02+0000",
"handle" : "geepas-2-face-quartz-heater-with-5-rods-1",
"body_html" : "<p data-mce-fragment="1">GEEPAS 2 Face Quartz Heater with 5 Rods (GQH9515N)</p>\n<p data-mce-fragment="1"><strong data-mce-fragment="1">Features:<br data-mce-fragment="1"></strong></p>\n<ul data-mce-fragment="1">\n<li data-mce-fragment="1">4 Heat Settings</li>\n<li data-mce-fragment="1">500/1000/1500/2000W</li>\n<li data-mce-fragment="1">Metal body</li>\n<li data-mce-fragment="1">Top and Front Heating Elements</li>\n</ul>",
"tags" : "Bestseller, Heater, New Arrival",
"title" : "GEEPAS 2 Face Quartz Heater with 5 Rods (GQH9515N)",
"image" : {
"product_id" : "7435299225813",
"height" : "1667",
"position" : null,
"id" : null,
"created_at" : "1970-01-01 00:00:02+0000",
"alt" : null,
"width" : "1330",
"src" : "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0475/7510/5697/products/GQH9515N-1.jpg?v=1636194584",
"variant_ids" : null,
"updated_at" : "1970-01-01 00:00:02+0000",
"admin_graphql_api_id" : "gid://shopify/ProductImage/34506789716181"
},
"vendor" : "GEEPAS",
"updated_at" : "1970-01-01 00:00:02+0000",
"template_suffix" : "",
"variants" : [
{
"fulfillment_service" : "manual",
"weight" : "0",
"position" : "1",
"sku" : "SOGQH9515N",
"inventory_policy" : "deny",
"title" : "Default Title",
"updated_at" : "1970-01-01 00:00:02+0000",
"weight_unit" : "kg",
"inventory_item_id" : "44109146259669",
"requires_shipping" : null,
"taxable" : null,
"image_id" : null,
"admin_graphql_api_id" : "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/42015321063637",
"compare_at_price" : null,
"option1" : "Default Title",
"id" : "42015321063637",
"grams" : "0",
"product_id" : "7435299225813",
"option2" : null,
"inventory_management" : "shopify",
"inventory_quantity" : "105",
"old_inventory_quantity" : "105",
"option3" : null,
"created_at" : "1970-01-01 00:00:02+0000",
"barcode" : "",
"price" : "4000.00"
}
],
"product_type" : "Electronics",
"published_scope" : "web",
"status" : "draft",
"images" : [
{
"product_id" : "7435299225813",
"height" : null,
"position" : "1",
"id" : null,
"created_at" : "1970-01-01 00:00:02+0000",
"alt" : null,
"width" : null,
"src" : "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0475/7510/5697/products/GQH9515N-1.jpg?v=1634584",
"variant_ids" : null,
"updated_at" : "1970-01-01 00:00:02+0000",
"admin_graphql_api_id" : "gid://shopify/ProductImage/34506789716181"
},
{
"product_id" : "7435299225813",
"height" : null,
"position" : "2",
"id" : null,
"created_at" : "1970-01-01 00:00:02+0000",
"alt" : null,
"width" : null,
"src" : "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0475/7510/5697/products/GQH9515N.jpg?v=1636194584",
"variant_ids" : null,
"updated_at" : "1970-01-01 00:00:02+0000",
"admin_graphql_api_id" : "gid://shopify/ProductImage/34506789781717"
}
]
})]

Comment: can u pls mention favouritesArray data

Comment: Show us your data structure and how you store your data (the array of dictionaries).
Also show how you retrieve this data. Then we can try to help you. Some example data would also be helpful.

Comment: I have added images. At the top of the post please check those.

Comment: Could you please insert code as  text rather that images of code ?

Comment: Also what are the warning you have ?

Comment: print(favouritesArray), and send that favouritesArray data

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: This also does not have to do with SwiftUI

Comment: @loremipsum yes sorry i have removed it thankyou for correction.

Comment: @Gowtham i have added the data of favourite array kindly check.

Comment: @loremipsum the other person(Gowtham) asked me to to print data for my array and show him and i did.